# Complex mongodb query with filter group and distinct

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I'm trying to write a complex query.
Your help will be really appreciated :-)
I have this schemas (After removed most of unnecessray properties) :

```js
var Track = Schema({
 channels: [Channel],
})

var Channel = Schema({
 revisions: [Revision]
});

var Revision = Schema({
 
 owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },

 revision: { type: Number, min: 0 },

 deleted: Boolean
})
```

Each track has many channels. Each channel can be found in many revisions (Save1 , Save2 after changes ,Save3 after changes etc...).
Channel can be deleted in revision x but can be restored in later revision (x+y).

I want to select all track's participants (All the channel owners that have an active channel).
Since channel can has many revisions , an active channel will be considered a channel that is not deleted in his last revision.
I want to distinct the result to a collection of users. the last revision of each channel can be different between different channels , but all of them are smaller than track.last Revision.

For following example , query will return["dima",'jhone']

```js
tracks collection
{
 channels: {
  {
   _id: 0
   revisions: [
    {
     owner: 'tal',
     revision: 0,
     deleted: false
    },{
     owner: 'tal',
     revision: 1,
     deleted: true
    }
   ]
  }, {
   _id: 1
   revisions: [
    {
     owner: 'dima',
     revision: 0,
     deleted: false
    }
   ]
  }, {
   _id: 2
   revisions: [
    {
     owner: 'Jhone',
     revision: 0,
     deleted: false
    },{
     owner: 'Jhone',
     revision: 1,
     deleted: true
    },{
     owner: 'Jhone',
     revision: 2,
     deleted: false
    },
   ]
  },{
   _id: 3
   revisions: [
    {
     owner: 'Jhone',
     revision: 0,
     deleted: false
    },
   ]
  }
 }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the expected output json to the post  and some sample docs from your collection ?

Comment: I have just added :-)